# Do I need the rsync daemon to take advantage of the differential copying ability of rsync?

Tags: rsync

This is a fairly simple question. To take advantage of the differential copying ability of rsync, does the receiver HAVE to be running rsync in daemon mode? Or can the sender just connect as necessary and send the diffs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, running rsync in daemon mode is not necessary.